# Regarding OpenMP Parallel SIMD Reductions

Tags: c, openmp

I have a rather simple for loop summing a very large array of double values `x` (100 mio data points) in C. I want to do this in parallel with SIMD reductions, using a specified number of threads. The OpenMP instruction in my reading should be:

```c
int nthreads = 4, l = 1e8;
double sum = 0.0;

#pragma omp parallel for simd num_threads(nthreads) reduction(+:sum)
for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) sum += x[i];
```

This however gives a compiler warning

```
loop not vectorized: the optimizer was unable to perform the requested transformation; the transformation might be disabled or specified as part of an unsupported transformation ordering [-Wpass-failed=transform-warning]
```

and running it with multiple threads is slower than single threaded. I'm using the Apple M1 Mac with `clang` (`Xclang`) v13.0.0 compiler. What I would like to know is: is this an issue with my system or is there actually something wrong / infeasible with this OpenMP instruction?

Comment: 1. Try different thread counts. 2. Why simd? Usually `omp parallel for` gives you all the speedup that a machine is capable of. Compilers can handle the simd stuff by themselves in many cases.

Comment: On godbolt.org I get the same warning message with clang 13 or 14, and no warning with clang >= 15. That said, with `-ffast-math` the compiler is likely able on vectorize on its own without an OpenMP directive (without -ffast-math it cannot because it changes the order of the operations).

Comment: Thanks @victor-eijkhout, actually in my case simple `#pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)` is faster than `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads) reduction(+:sum)` using any number of threads. So there is indeed something wrong at the compilation step. Thanks also @pieru, I think it could indeed be that such instructions are only supported by later compiler versions, I will try to update clang and see.

Comment: 3. What are you compilation options? Usually with `-O2` and higher the compiler will simd-ize nicely. 4. I've heard that Apple's native `clang` may not do OpenMP. Download a recent external compiler. I use gcc 12.2.0 which has pretty good OMP support.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout doesn't the auto-vectorization of a sum like this require some `fast-math` enabled? At least on gcc it makes a huge difference.

Comment: Multithreading such as loop is usually not very efficient, as this is typically a memory bound code (low arithmetic intensity). That said, it can be different on a M1 chip because of the very large transfer rates between the CPU and the RAM.

Comment: `fast-math` is not feasible here because it breaks other parts of the program. Other compilation options are `-O3` and `-fopenmp`. Still trying to compile with the homebrew clang, system clang cannot be updated.

Comment: I got it now compiling and running fine on clang 16. Multithreading gives a slight speedup, but indeed not very worthwhile. Simple SIMD vectorization seems the best option on the M1.

Comment: @PierU Yes, it's memory bound but modern processors have a lot of bandwidth. IIRC I get 40x speedup on my 56 core Cascade Lake.

Comment: @Sebastian It's not uncommon to use different compiler options per program section.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout thanks, that's true, but this is actually for an R package and I have no control over the compiler options as binaries are built by the Comprehensive R Archive Network upon submission of a source package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiles without warning on clang >= 15, but performance depends on the system. With the Apple M1 it seems that multithreading does not add much to the SIMD vectorization and single threaded execution with a `#pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)` instruction is about as good as it gets.